# Why when uploading file format 20%.jpg i'm getting exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

The reason is the %
If i'm uploading 20 files and they are all jpg no problems but if one of the files names is for example 20%.jpg or 50%.jpg i can't upload them.

I can edit and see the images on my hard disk but i can't upload them.

Now for example for the test in files index 0 i have: D:\5%.jpg
So txf and fn both contain: D:\5%.jpg

This is the top part of the method i upload files to my ftp server:

The exception happen when i'm calling the method createDirectory in this method.

```
private void StringArrayUploadFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string txf in files)
                {
                    string fn = txf;
                    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(txf);
                    f.TargetFolder = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
                    f.TargetFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(txf);
                    f.TargetFolder = Path.GetFullPath(txf).Replace(":", "").Replace("\\", "/");
                    string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName(f.TargetFolder);
                    int index = txf.IndexOf(filenameonly);
                    string left = txf.Substring(0, index);
                    f.TargetFolder = Path.GetFullPath(left).Replace(":", "").Replace("\\", "");
                    createDirectory(f.TargetFolder);
```

The variable f is FtpSettings:

```
public class FtpSettings
    {
        public string Host, Username, Password, TargetFolder, SourceFile;
        public bool Passive;
        public int Port = 21;
    }
```

files is string[]

The exception happen when i'm trying to create the directory for the file on the ftp server.
That's in the method createDirectory i'm calling from the download method:

```
createDirectory(f.TargetFolder);
```

This is the createDirectory method:

```
public void createDirectory(string newDirectory)
        {
            try
            {
                string FtpHost = f.Host + "/" + newDirectory;
                if (!FtpHost.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                    FtpHost = "ftp://" + FtpHost;
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FtpHost);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                ftpResponse1 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                ftpResponse1.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }
```

In the variable newDirectory i have: D
That's fine so i'm not sure where the % or why the % make the problem.

The exception heppen inside the createDirectory method on the line:

```
ftpResponse1 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.FtpProgress.createDirectory(String newDirectory) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\FtpProgress.cs:line 270
  InnerException:
```

Line 270 is:

```
ftpResponse1 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: And the exception is happen only with files that have % in the name for example test%.jpg or 5%.jpg i checked it on 5%.jpg but also other files with % make the exception.  Regular files without % for example 5.jpg or test.jpg are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe that in ftp URI special characters like `20%` or other?
try to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` and `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Comment: I didn't find good example how to use it but what does it do ? Remove spaces or the % from the file name ? The file name is 5%.jpg so it should be also the same name on my ftp server: 5%.jpg and not 5.jpg

Comment: URI has special characters that you cannot use in your request(such as spaces, backspaces and etc). And if you want send this special symbol you must encode this character to valid URI string.
After this in your string special characters has been replaced to '%code' (for example 'space' to '%20'). You use in URI symbol '%'  that mean beginning of encoded symbol, and '%.' is incorrect symbol.
If you will encode URI '5%.jpg'  you get folder '5%.jpg', but in request will be send URI-valid string like '5%25.jpg'.